# dhcpd not responding to request from MAC already in the lease

Tags: linux, dhcp-server

My dhcp server on linux machine has a specific host declaration for MAC within one subnet. When my other machine boot up over network using PXE, it receives the right IP address. However this dhcp reply contain other "options" that i want to utilize during booting phase for which i have a script that runs before init. How can i fetch those options?

I have also tried to send new dhcp request over the same network card but my server don't like to respond. Is it because my server already has a lease for this specific MAC?

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, I would send an Inform message.  If that fails, then I would try a Request.

In either case, I would sniff the network to see what traffic is being passed.

Before trying to get this information I would ensure there aren't any other programs listening for responses.  They are likely to get the responses you are looking for.